# Flutter Local_Notifications, how to see all my notifications that are already set?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want my users to be able to setup the notifications themselves, this means that a notification that has been set, needs to be able to be seen in the UI. However, all I can find on the local_notifications page is how to add one and delete one.

How do I get a list of all my notifications that are already setup, so that they can be edited?

Am I gonna have to store the data in a datebase?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all your pending notifications from the below method.

```
final List<PendingNotificationRequest> pendingNotificationRequests =
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests();
```

Here is the document [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#retrieving-pending-notification-requests).